# Create alias for the cy.route when called for more than 2 time doesn't work property with cy.wait

Tags: automation, cypress

I have set up an alias for the particular route. It perfectly works when it gets called for the first time. But I have the same post action getting called multiple times during my automation script. Which affects the cy.wait() behavior and it ends up in Timeout error with NO RESPONSE FROM SERVER.

```
Cy.route("POST","*/*/ABC/METHODNAME").as("getDataFromServer"); // executed 4 times
Cy.route("POST","*/*/ABC/SecondMETHODNAME").as("getDataFromMethod2"); // executed 6 times
Cy.route("POST","*/*/ABC/THIRDMETHODNAME").as("getFromMethod3"); // actual request which will give the page output (html code)

cy.wait(["@getDataFromServer","@getDataFromServer","@getDataFromServer","@getDataFromMethod2","@getDataFromMethod2","@getDataFromMethod2","@getDataFromMethod2","@getDataFromServer","@getDataFromMethod2","@getDataFromMethod2","@getFromMethod3"];
cy.get(); // rest of the code assert and expect;
```

I have multiple calls to `getDataFromServer` and `getDataFromMethod2` before `getFromMethod3`. So, I put a wait on it.
There is 35 scripts written when running all those scripts using `RUN ALL TESTS` few scripts randomly breaks.

`cy.Wait()` timeout waiting for 100000ms for the 3rd response for "@getDataFromMethod2" No response from the server.
or sometimes throws
`cy.Wait()` timeout waiting for 100000ms for the 5th response for "@getDataFromMethod2" No response from the server.
[image]

Comment: If `getFromMethod3` is the last fired and the one you care about, could you just wait for that one and ignore the others?

Comment: Yes, I was following the same earlier but it was failing frequently with the error that "Timeout retrying cy.wait() waiting 100000ms for the response to the route 'getFromMethod3". No response ever occured.